# How to do a fancy print in ipython using sympy.pprint()

Tags: python, sympy, pprint

I'm trying to pprint() in Sympy a variable that I call barphi. What I want to get is

```
$\bar{\phi}$
```

when printed as `pprint(barphi)`.

I try

```
barphy = Symbol('\bar{phi}')
```

but it does not work. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This was answered on the [SymPy mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sympy/xPwzWrvH_zw/4AURJ1TCF04J).

There are two issues with what you wrote

First, Python converts `\` + character in strings as escaping. The `\b` in your string becomes a backspace (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart).

You need to either escape the `\`, i.e., use `'\\bar{\\phi}$'`, or, much easier, if you don't care about escaping, use a raw string, which just means to put an `r` in front of the quotes, like `r'\bar{\phi}'`.

Second, if you want to get LaTeX, `pprint()` will not do it (`pprint` pretty prints to 2D text). You should use `init_printing()` to enable LaTeX printing in the notebook.

Finally, as pointed out by Julien Rioux on the mailing list, you can just name the symbol `phibar`, and SymPy will automatically render it as `\bar{\phi}`, as you can see here even in Unicode

```
In [11]: Symbol('phibar')
Out[11]: φ̅
```

Comment: thank you very much @asmeurer for your answer. But in my system is not working as it does in yours, for example I dont get the bar over phi in
In [12]: pprint(Symbol('phibar'))
phibar

In [13]: pprint(Symbol('phi'))
φ

Comment: You need to do that in an environment that supports Unicode, including combining characters. And don't forget to run `init_printing()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to get the latex code rather than printing it, you can do so by:

```
In [2]: from sympy.printing.latex import latex, translate

In [3]: latex(translate('phibar'),mode='inline')
Out[3]: '$\\bar{\\phi}$'
```

you can see the documentation for **latex** function [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html?highlight=latex#sympy.printing.latex.latex)

The documentation for **translate** function are

```
Check for a modifier ending the string.  If present, convert the
modifier to latex and translate the rest recursively.

Given a description of a Greek letter or other special character,
return the appropriate latex.

Let everything else pass as given.

>>> from sympy.printing.latex import translate
>>> translate('alphahatdotprime')
"{\\dot{\\hat{\\alpha}}}'"
```